# Check if database and/or table exists

Tags: php, sql, database, zend-framework, installation

I am trying to write a simple installation script using Zend Framework. It's supposed to run a few tests:

- test if the database specified in application.ini exists (or if there's access to it).
- if it does, test if a table called `user` exists within the database
- if it does, check if there's a site admin user

Should any of the steps fail, the controller will take care of redirecting the user to the proper step of the installation process.

I created a model with the following code:

```
public function verify () {
    $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter(); //throws exception
    if ($db == null) return self::NO_BATABASE;
    $result = $db->describeTable('user'); //throws exception
    if (empty($result)) return self::NO_USER;
    $result = $db->fetchRow('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1');
    if ($result == null) return self::USER_EMPTY;
    else return self::OK;
}
```

However, I overestimated the functions I have used. `getDefaultAdapter()` may return `null`, but in case there's no database to connect to, an exception is thrown. Same happens with `describeTable()`, which throws an exception instead of returning an empty array.

My question is therefore: how do I check whether the database/table exists without getting an exception or error?

Comment: What about using try{} and catch{}, to catch the exception from getDefaultAdapter?

Comment: Nothing wrong with exceptions, just wrap the calls in a try { } catch statement http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rough example :

```
public function verify () {
    try{
       $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter(); //throws exception
       if ($db == null) return self::NO_BATABASE;
    }catch(Exception $e){
       return self::NO_BATABASE;
    }
    try{
       $result = $db->describeTable('user'); //throws exception
       if (empty($result)) return self::NO_USER;
    }catch(Exception $e){
       return self::NO_USER;
    }
    $result = $db->fetchRow('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1');
    if ($result == null) return self::USER_EMPTY;
    else return self::OK;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there were some Zend-specific functions for that, but this works OK, so I'll settle with this. Just a remark: `catch` needs parentheses (`catch(Exception $e) {...`) :).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'll edit it. Just did a fast copy/past thingy :p

Comment: just as a side note, you can use the IF (NOT) EXISTS functions of SQl to verify if a database/table exists.

Comment: @Simon : You're right and, even if an answer is accepted, you should put what you think could help the OP (or future comers) as an answer. But, here, using that kind of PDO won't require such query since it's usually already the cause of the exception thrown.

Comment: @Simon: I tried these first, but with Zend Framework, they just didn't do the trick :(.

Answer (score 0):

describeTable will work but will error if the table does not exists, so I went for the below as it will will return 0 or 1 if the table exists.

```
 $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
 $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = \'table name\'';
 $result = $db->query($sql)->fetch();
```